# How to fix server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain"?

Tags: angular, docker, mime

I have a frontend app that is using module federation architecture. It contains one shell application and 3 micro-frontends. I built container for each of these 4 apps. When I run these containers and go to chrome, open my shell it works just fine. I then try to navigate to any of the other applications via my navbar but I get the following errors:

[image]

When inspecting network, remoteEntry.mjs is loaded:
[image]

I am able to open and examine it:

[image]

Also, i tried changing my registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js\Content Type to text/javascript but it didn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated as am new to the module federation architecture as well as dockers.

Edit: I am using Nginx server with this config:

```
 events{}
 http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile for one of the micro-frontends:

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .


RUN npm install -g @nrwl/cli
RUN npm install --force
RUN npx nx build graphs --configuration=production

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./apps/graphs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=node app/dist/apps/graphs /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Edit: I tried adding

```
types 
        {
            application/javascript mjs;
        }
```

to my nginx config, but now i get this:

[image]

Comment: What web server are you using in your Docker containers to serve files? It seems like it is setting the incorrect `content-type` header, which your browser (correctly) refuses to execute.

Comment: @superhawk610 I am using Nginx. I edited question and provided further information. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Angular NX Module Federation, fixed it by changing nginx config file inside every microfrontends. That fixes MIME and CORS errors.

MIME: `types { ... }`
CORS: `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` inside *server{}*

This is nginx config file:

```js
events{}
http {
    include mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    types 
        {
             text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css scss;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js mjs;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! For some reason i didn't have these types in mime.types and had to add them manually in every micro-frontend Nginx config file. It works for now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the line

```
application/x-javascript    mjs;
```

in the file /etc/nginx/mime.types;

Comment: I updated the question. After adding the type application/javascript mjs; in my config file i can't load shell but but just get plain html as shown in image i provided in my edit.